# How to create a unique ID for amazon web services in Android

Tags: java, android, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I am new to Android coming from iOS development, and am attempting to make the Android version of my iOS app.  I was wondering how I can autogenerate a unique ID like I have in objective-c.  In objective-c, the syntax to autogenerate an ID looks like this: `[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager].identityId;`

Does anyone know what this would look like in the Android version?  Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create unique Id in Android too. Its actually 32 characters in length. Below is a sample code:

```
String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```